# Javascript if else with click dont

Tags: javascript, if-statement, click, counter, addeventlistener

i need your help, i'm trying to programm a button that only works if you have 20.

here is my code:

```
const number = document.getElementById('number')
const button = document.getElementById('button')
const button_two = document.getElementById('button2')

let counter = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter++
number.innerHTML = counter
})



if(number >= 20){
    button_two.addEventListener('click', function(){
        counter++
        counter++
        number.innerHTML = counter
    })
}else{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach one listener to a parent element (`.buttons`). Use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. If the child element that fired the event is a button work through the conditions.

```js
// Cache the elements you'll be using
const number = document.querySelector('.number');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const plusTwo = document.querySelector('#plusTwo');

// Add one listener to the button container
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

let counter = 0;

function handleClick(e) {
  
  // If the child element that fired the event
  // is a button
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    
    // Destructure its id
    const { id } = e.target;
    
    // Add one, and if the counter is 20
    // enable the `plusTwo` button
    if (id === 'plusOne') {
      ++counter;
      if (counter === 20) plusTwo.disabled = false;
    }
    
    // Add two
    if (id === 'plusTwo') counter += 2;

    // Minus one
    if (id === 'minusOne') --counter;
  
  }
  
  // Update the number
  number.textContent = counter;

}
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button id="plusOne">Plus one</button>
  <button id="plusTwo" disabled>Plus two</button>
  <button id="minusOne">Minus one</button>
</section>
<div class="number"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) / [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: BTW, you dont need empty else statment if you are not plnning on doing something else. Just delete it

Comment: if i now have a button with which i want to subtract a number, how do i do that? i try it with: number.textContent - 2; in a button with function :(

Comment: I rewrote the answer. Now there's just one function that checks the id of the clicked button and then using a set of conditions updates the number. Hope that helps. @B34Rocky

Comment: sorry i´m new here, i did it :)